# Cannot refresh ListView which gets data from JSON when click button from its Adapter in Android

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

I am new with this and I try to have a ListView which get data from JSON

I have in its Adapter a button which updates a MySQL field

I try to update the ListView by reloading it but nothing is displayed

```
viewHolder.Valid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           final DailyCrud mycrud = new DailyCrud();
           mycrud.Extend(String.valueOf(id));

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Actions.class);

            getContext().startActivity(intent);

            ((Activity)getContext()).finish();


        }
    });
```

and I get a null exception message in a toast message, 
how I can fix this?

Comment: Add stacktrace and Use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh your list

Comment: I get the same with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); added

Comment: I am not having skype

Comment: Post your code, so someone verify it

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it, it was a spelling Error of Actions.class thank you